# Getting 0% coverage in Sonarqube , Using nosetests for generating coverage.xml

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, nose

I'm working on a project where code coverage needs to display in Sonarqube.
We are framing dockerfile.test where at ENTRYPOINT nosetests is provided. setup.cfg file is created putting all required nosetests plugins. Then sonar-project.properties file has been created for sonarqube reference. And a stage named "Test/Sonar" is created in jenkins ,

below has the script of all above mentioned files.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc gfortran perl libtest-utf8-perl \
libtest-file-perl libtest-files-perl cpanminus build-essential curl libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev \
gfortran liblzma-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libpq-dev  procps libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev ldap-utils  git

RUN cpanm install File::Copy::Recursive

RUN pip install numpy && pip install scipy pandas scikit-learn
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt 
COPY test_requirements.txt /test_requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /test_requirements.txt 

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

#Install Mim
RUN python mim-python-client/setup.py install
RUN mkdir -p /local/tmp/mim-cache
RUN chmod -R 777 /local/tmp/mim-cache

#Install Extract
WORKDIR /app/extract-rules
RUN bash --posix ./dev/build.sh
RUN cp ./bin/python_parser.py /opt/extract/bin/


WORKDIR /app/backend/worker

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

ENTRYPOINT nosetests
```

```
[nosetests]
verbose=3 
with-xunit=1
xunit-file=nosetests.xml
with-coverage=1
cover-xml=1
cover-package=.
exclude-dir=test
```

```
sonar.projectKey=IPA_NIP
sonar.projectName=IPA_NIP
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.language=py
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml
sonar.python.xunit.reportPaths=nosetests.xml
sonar.python.xunit.skipDetails=false
sonar.sources=backend/orch, backend/worker, webserver/pinap 
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/IPA_NIP/lcov.info
sonar.python.coveragePlugin=cobertura
```

```
                stage ('Test/Sonar') {
                    
                    steps {
                        // This specific examples expects that you have a Dockerfile.test that you build, then run to generate test results.
                        // Since different projects can vary however, you should make sure you use the solution that works best for you.
                        sh "docker build . -f Dockerfile.test -t python-test:${BUILD_ID}"

                        sh '''docker run -u 50001255:25 -v "$(pwd)":/app python-test:${BUILD_ID}'''
                        sh '''sed -i 's|filename="|filename="'"$(pwd)"'/|' coverage.xml'''
                        
                        sonarScan('Sonar')
                    }

                    // Make test results visible in Jenkins UI if the install step completed successfully
                    post {
                        success {
                            junit testResults: 'nosetests.xml', allowEmptyResults: true
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I couldn't able to find why I'm getting 0% coverage at sonarqube.

dockerfile.test is executing without any error. I'm getting status about tests (Unit test) as OK. But I'm getting a warning

```
WARN: The report '/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/v_AutomationAuthenticationScript/coverage.xml' seems to be empty, ignoring. '{}'
org.sonar.plugins.python.EmptyReportException: null
```

Could anyone help me out with my queries?